Dashes in Rinex format Examples
I'm trying to understand what does all that dashes mean in Rinex file

----|---1|0---|---2|0---|---3|0---|---4|0---|---5|0---|---6|0---|---7|0---|---8|

https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/CORS/RINEX211.txt
see Table A7 example.
